# CSS styling for paragraph in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set a style for paragraph which is fetched via JS.

Here is what I have:

```
  var info = "<p>" + meeting.summary + "</p>;
```

I want to apply some styling and I am trying the code below:

```
var info= "<p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">" + meeting.summary + "</p>;
```

But that doesn't work and the JS code does not work correctly. How I can use CSS for JavaScript variables such as the one I am trying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To work with what you've got right now use this (notice the use of `'`):

```
var info= '<p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;">' + meeting.summary + '</p>';
```

But I would simply suggest to add a class to the `p` and style that in CSS:

```
// JS
var info = '<p class="info">' + meeting.summary + '</p>';

// CSS
.info {font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: small;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would fetch the paragraph from the DOM and manipulate its attributes using Javascript [like this](http://noobflash.com/set-style-dynamically-with-javascript/)